# Python: animate FancyArrows with matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, patch

I'm trying to get a Python script to visualize N arrows (which represent N phases in an electric machine).
I've got a kind of solution, but after running the code and the animation, Python crashes.

This is not a critical error, but could be in the future. By the way, any suggestion about the code would be appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.collections as collections


#define the specfications of fasors
t=np.linspace(0,1/50,100)
Iamp=10
f=50
  
N=7
PHIs=[2*np.pi*n/N for n in range(N)]

#PHASOR BUILDER:
def build_Phasor(t,phi0):
    return {"dx":Iamp*np.cos(2*np.pi*f*t+phi0),
            "dy":Iamp*np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t+phi0)}


#DEFINE GRAPHICAL 

fig = plt.figure()    
ax = fig.gca()

ax.set_ylim(top=Iamp,bottom=-Iamp)  # set safe limit to ensure that all data is visible.
ax.set_xlim(right=Iamp,left=-Iamp)  # set safe limit to ensure that all data is visible.
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')


arrows=[plt.arrow  (0,0,
                        build_Phasor(t=0,phi0=phi)["dx"],
                        build_Phasor(t=0,phi0=phi)["dy"],
                        head_width=10/30,  head_length=10/10,
                        length_includes_head=True,   animated=False)
            for phi in PHIs]
collection=collections.PatchCollection(arrows)
ax.add_collection(collection)




def animate(t):
    ax.patches.clear()
    arrows=[(  plt.arrow(0, 0,
                            dx=(Iamp*np.cos(2*np.pi*f*t+phi)),  dy=(Iamp*np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t+phi)),  #what if I call buid_Fasor() here?
                            head_width=10/30,  head_length=10/10,
                            length_includes_head=True,   animated=False)) for phi in PHIs]

    # collection.set_paths(arrows)   ## why do i get an output with this line commented?




anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, 
                               interval=150, frames=t,
                               )

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

After some scratching, I've get the correct answer.
The problem is appearing here:

```
def animate(t):
ax.patches.clear()
arrows=[(  plt.arrow(0, 0,
                        dx=(Iamp*np.cos(2*np.pi*f*t+phi)),  dy=(Iamp*np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t+phi)),  #what if I call buid_Fasor() here?
                        head_width=10/30,  head_length=10/10,
                        length_includes_head=True,   animated=False)) for phi in PHIs]
```

The command plt.arrow()=matplotlib.pyplot.arrow() is a method to generate a FancyArrow object (patch) and **adding** it to an axe. [Reference](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.arrow.html)

The proper way to do plot the FancyArrows objects is to **generate the arrow** by [one command](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.FancyArrow.html), and **add it to the target axes** with [another command](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.add_patch.html).

In order to animate, we have to secuentially modify the parameters of each arrow every time we run animation.FuncAnimation.

**Arrow Generation:**

```
def graph_initial_plot():
for i,phase in enumerate(CarthesianLocus_Phases):
     ax[0,1].add_patch(patches.FancyArrow(0, 0, phase.phasor.dx, phase.phasor.dy,
                            head_width = 10/30,  head_length = 10/10, width=.1,
                            length_includes_head = True, color = colour_list[i]))
```

**Arrow Rotation**

```
def animations(t):
def phasor_rotation(t):
    for i,arrow in enumerate(ax[0,1].patches):
        phase=CarthesianLocus_Phases[i]
        arrow.set_data(dx=phase.phasor.dx, dy=phase.phasor.dy)
   
def wave_displacement(t):
    for i,phase in enumerate(CarthesianLocus_Phases):
        ax[0,0].lines[i].set_data(phase.wave.t,phase.wave.y)   
        #we get horizontal waveforms, 
        #we need to add points to the line (or redefine line)

calculate_next_point(t)
phasor_rotation(t)
wave_displacement(t)
```